# What is the difference between "gaja", "ĝoja" and "feliĉa"?

Tags: word-choice

*Gaja, ĝoja* and *feliĉa* are all *happy* in English. But I have gotten the impression that they are not synonyms. What is the difference between the three adjectives? When should I use each one?

Comment: Good question. I always just use feliĉa because I like keeping things simple. I have always assumed, perhaps falsely, that they are similar to the English words that we don't hear anymore except at Christmas. Gaja (gay/merrry) - ĝoja (joyful) - feliĉa (happy).

Answer (score 9):

*Feliĉa* is happy as in *content*. This is not the best translation but reflects the long-term nature of the status. You are *feliĉa* if you have a good life, a happy family, no troubles. You can largely influence this feeling by your life decisions, or the general feeling of luck. Actual luck (getting a good roll in dice) can also be described by *feliĉo*, but that's probably just an influence of the earlier languages.

*Ĝoja* describes the transient feeling of happiness of something that made you feel good. I think a close word in English is to *rejoice* (the base form *ĝoj/i* is also a verb). You can *ĝoji* for someone close's success, for example. It does not automatically make you *feliĉa*. But you probably are a *feliĉa* person (in general) if little things like seeing flowers (individual events) make you *ĝoja*.

*Gaja* is what English traditionally described as *gay*: cheerful, jolly, merry.

One can be *gaja* (cheerful) when dancing and laughing around at someone's wedding, while being *ĝoja* (rejoicing) for one's friends' big day, and *feliĉa* (happy) realizing how good it is to have friends and opportunities for a good time.

Another example is that one would probably not rejoice (*ĝoji*) in being poor, but could easily feel more *feliĉa* than someone rich but living under stress and fear of a sudden loss. On the other hand, one can be *ĝoja* for winning a lottery despite otherwise being *malfeliĉa* because other things haven't been going so well lately, or because of one's depressive mood.

Answer (score 5):

Shooting from the hip here (i.e. without checking references)

- *Gaja* has to do with frivolity, enthusiastic celebration, and levity. *Ni gaje kantis*.
- *ĝoja* is related to the joyful emotion that you feel from within. *Mi ĝojas pro via sukceso.*
- *feliĉa* can also describe an emotion, but often has to do with luck or good fortune. *Feliĉe tio ne okazis.*

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll be hard to explain the difference using the English language, but let me try!

- *gaja* refers to one's state, mood. It can be seen in the external signs: gestures, smile, laughter.
- *ĝoja* refers to one's character or feeling of pleasure in one's heart, caused by perceived goodness (real or imaginary) around oneself.
- *feliĉa* refers to one's fate, fortune, luck or good chance, feel of satisfaction with one's life and thus is much more long-term thing.

So scientists may study how *feliĉaj* are people, what qualities of life make them feel long-term satisfaction. Optimists are *ĝojaj* people, because their temperament makes them always look on the bright side of life. But from time to time everyone can be *gaja*, because of a good joke, or *malgaja*, because of sad news. It's a short-term state, independent from one's life satisfaction or natural tendencies for optimism or pessimism.